# Get value inside span tag in second td element in row

Tags: jquery

How can I get the value in a span tag that is in the second td element of a series of table rows?

Here is an example of one of the table rows:

```
<tr onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}" class="dataRow even first">
<td colspan="1" id="j_id0:theForm:selectedlist:theTable:0:leadname" class="dataCell">
    <span id="j_id0:theForm:selectedlist:theTable:0:j_id93">Shelia Abraham</span>
</td>
<td colspan="1" id="j_id0:theForm:selectedlist:theTable:0:solutionInterest" class="dataCell">
    <span id="j_id0:theForm:selectedlist:theTable:0:j_id94">Birst</span>
</td>
</tr>
```

I want to get the value from the span tag in the second td element for each row.  In the example above, the value would be `Birst`.

Here is my JQuery:

```
    j$(document).ready(function(){  
        var dataRows = j$('tr.dataRow');
        dataRows.each(function(index, elem) {
            console.log(index);
            console.log(elem);
        });         
    });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TTEg7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `:nth-child(n)` at this context,  And keep in mind that `:nth-child(n)` index starts from `1` not `0`

```
$('tr.dataRow td:nth-child(2) span').each(function(){
  // Your code here
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bKQKx/)

And if you want to grab those values in an array then use `.map()`,

```
var spanValues = $('tr.dataRow td:nth-child(2) span').map(function(){
   return $(this).text();
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/52w7E/2/)**

Use **[`eq(n)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)** (where n : 0- n) selector,

```
$('tr.dataRow').each(function () {
    console.log($('td:eq(1) span', this).text());
});
```